# Sorting information in Datagrid

Tags: sorting, datagrid, vb6

I have a datagrid linked to an access database in VB6. how do i sort the data in ascending order when the user clicks the command button.

My Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  connSearch.Open connstr
  Adodc1.ConnectionString = Conn.connstr
  Set StudentTable.DataSource = Adodc1
  Adodc1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSort_Click()
  Dim LNsql As String
  connSearch.Close
  connSearch.Open connstr
  LNsql = "select * from Table1 order By LastName" & " " & StudentTable.Columns(2).Caption & "Asc"
  StudentTable.Refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your recordset's `CursorLocation` property is set to adUseClient you don't need to close and re-open the recordset. Just use the [Recordset.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675783(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

```
Private Sub cmdSort_Click()
    Adodc1.Recordset.Sort = "LastName"   'data field name
End Sub
```